Not able extract all the tags from pdf using iText-8 getAllFormField Method
As per the iText 8 version migration from iText 5.5.
We are unable to extract the tag from PDF by using new iText 8 code but able to extract using old iText 5.5 code.
Below is the code to get the tags.
As per New Code
PdfAcroForm pdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
 or
PdfAcroForm pdfAcroForm = PdfFormCreator.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
Map<String, PdfFormField> formFieldMap = pdfAcroForm.getAllFormFields();

As per old code:
reader = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader(docdByteArray);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
AcroFields acroFields = stamper.getAcroFields();

We also tried Apache PDFBox but we are getting the same result which we got using new iText 8.
The issue happens with only one or two PDFs. We have one other PDF with same tag and we are able extract that tag using new and old code.
We are able to extract that tag from original template but after prefill we failed.
In my case is the PDF file corrupted or is fields structure disturbed or any other issue?
Not able to attached PDF docs because it's confidential document.
We are expecting the same result that we got using iText 5.5 version from original and prefilled PDFs.

By "tags" I assume you mean form field names. In old times (say, the early 200x years) there were some PDF form generators that "forgot" to include the fields in the document AcroForm dictionary (where they need to be according to spec), so those fields could only be found by analyzing the pages. Consequentially the old iText versions contained code to analyze the pages and find extra fields. Nowadays PDF creators usually do correctly fill the AcroForm dictionary, so the re-designed iText 7 stopped looking for such orphan fields. This might be the issue in your case.

tag name is "base "   and below is the format im getting from original pdf template.


<</AP 7 0 R /DA /TiRo 0 Tf  /F 4 /FT /Tx /P 1 0 R /Rect [201.0 679.139 539.04 693.164 ] /Subtype /Widget /T base /TU Base Number >>


<</DA /Helv 0 Tf 0 g  /DR <</Font <</Helv 4 0 R /TiRo 5 0 R >> >> /Fields [6 0 R ] >>



The main difference between iText5 and 8 in terms of handling acroform fields is that

In iText 8 we read form fields starting from form fields in acroform dictionary and then going down to the possible kids which might be form fields or widget annotations.
In iText5 on its turn we start from the widget annotations on pages and going up to the possible parents.

Also note that widget annotation dictionaries may contain form field's data.
So here the difference comes, if your annotation is present only on the page and is not referenced in acro form dictionary by any mean (neither directly in fields array nor as a child of any field), iText 8 will not treat it as a form field related annotation (in accordance to the pdf spec) and will not return it.
You can try to catch it though on your own and add to the acro form, and thus fix the document. The code would be as follows:
private Map<String, PdfFormField> populateFields(PdfDocument doc) {
    Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= doc.getNumberOfPages(); ++i) {
        PdfPage page = doc.getPage(i);
        List<PdfAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
        for (PdfAnnotation annot : annotations) {
            if (!annot.getSubtype().equals(PdfName.Widget)) {
                continue;
            }
            PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.makeFormField(annot.getPdfObject(), doc);
            if (field != null) {
                fields.put(field.getFieldName().toUnicodeString(), field);
            }
        }
    }

    return fields;
}

Note that this code doesn't take acro form fields hierarchy into account, only plain list of widget annotations which might be or might not be referenced from the acro form.
So if you find anything unique in the fields map returned by this method comparing to PdfAcroForm.getAllFormFields(), you can add it into acro form using PdfAcroForm.addField.

thanx. it really help me to get things clear. now we got the tags from pdf using your suggestion but as you mentioned that tags not from actual acroform field so now I'm not able to flattened the fields. pdfAcroForm.flattenFields(); pdfAcroForm.partialFormFlattening(pdfTag); pdfAcroForm.disableRegenerationForAllFields()                                                                                   Now these methods not working for that field and field remains editable after prefill.

Please be aware that the problem fields strictly speaking are broken: Valid fields are added (directly or indirectly) to AcroForm. Thus maybe you should preprocess your PDFs and check if there are such orphan fields. If there are such orphans, this preprocessing step should add the fields to the AcroForm.

As @mkl said, you have to add this field to the AcroForm to be able to flatten it. So before flattening the fields you should call pdfAcroForm.addField(pdfTag, null) for the missing field. Second parameter is null meaning the page to add a field its annotation to. But you already have it on a correct page so pass null there.
